# Handling null types in String prototype

Tags: javascript, string

I have a function

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
```

Where I need to adapt this to return "" (empty string)

```
"".capitalize must return ""
undefined.capitalize must return ""
null.capitalize must return ""
```

I have tried with

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1) || "";
}
```

but for undefined I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'capitalize' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:6
```

Comment: You want to capitalise 1st character ?

Comment: `undefined.capitalize` or `null.capitalize` will never be able to work. You’ll have to use a function instead of a prototype method for these. Alternatively, if you use `String.prototype.capitalize.call(undefined)` and `String.prototype.capitalize.call(null)`, you may use `return (this || "").charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1)`. Consider `??` instead of `||`. Keep in mind that extending native prototypes is discouraged.

Comment: I agree with @SebastianSimon. `undefined.capitalize` should not be a thing. If you use any function on `undefined` or `null` it will return: "TypeError: undefined has no properties".

Comment: you are calling a String prototype on null and undefined. But null and undefined are not string types. If you want to achieve your desired result, jus create a function that does that.

Answer (score 0):

null and undefined are not string type so you'll always get a type error. your approach won't work. But you can create a function that does that

```js
function capitalize(str){
    if(str === null || str === undefined ){return ""}
    else {return str = str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)}
}

let str1 = null
let str2 = undefined
let str3 = "abc"
console.log(capitalize(str1))
console.log(capitalize(str2))
console.log(capitalize(str3))
```

Comment: You don’t get the TypeError because `null` and `undefined` are not of type String; you get the error because reading properties off of `null` and `undefined` isn’t possible.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yeah. correct. My wording wasn't the most accurate, but that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as useful answer.

```
function capitalize(l){return null==l?"":null==l?"":l.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+l.slice(1)}
```

Comment: Why is `null==l?"":` repeated?

Answer (score -2):

If `this.length` is more than 0 you return `""`.

```js
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
  return (this.length > 0) ? this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1) : "";
}

console.log(typeof "test string".capitalize(), ":", "test string".capitalize());
console.log(typeof "".capitalize(), ":", "".capitalize());
```

Comment: This doesn’t address `null` or `undefined` at all.